# Moving iOS app to using Storyboards while retaining some views programmatically

Tags: ios5, uiview, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to convert my existing project into using Storyboards, so that I can visually lay out my views. I still need to load some views into other views programmatically though.

(as a side note .. I used to program in Flash ActionScript, and am quite new to programming in iOS and have only taken a primer to Objective-C, so I have some tremendous "holes" that I am trying to work through).

My layout is something like this:

A calendar has a subview to create its cells - 'gridView'. I originally had this view created programmatically, which in turn added its own subviews for the calendar cells (the squares that show the date). I have added the gridView to the storyboard successfully and it does display the calendar cells (which are added programmatically by the gridView). I had successfully been able to display the correct dates onto the calendar, which I now have broken using storyboards and am trying to decide if I need to go back to creating the gridView programmatically, or if I can indeed do what I want to do in Storyboards.

So here is where I am stuck:

In my gridView I use draw rect to create all of the cell subviews:

```
// lay down the individual cells to build the calendar
    // 7 days across x 6 weeks down
    const CGSize gCellSize = {self.frame.size.width/7, (self.frame.size.height-20)/6};
    for(int w=0;w<6;w++) //6 weeks in the calendar
    {
        for(int d=0;d<7;d++) //7 days in a week
        {
            // ------------------ setting up the CELLVIEW ----------------------//
            CGRect calendarCellRect=CGRectMake(d*gCellSize.width,w*gCellSize.height+20, gCellSize.width, gCellSize.height);
            CalendarCellView *cellView=[[CalendarCellView alloc] initWithFrame:calendarCellRect];
            [self addSubview:cellView];
        }
    }
```

so here is my issue:
When I created everything programmatically, the gridView was loaded as a subview to the parent view, and the cellViews were laid out just fine. After the gridView is loaded, the parent view would continue on with a method (displayDates - inside gridView) that loops through those subviews, and adds their appropriate date to each cellView.

but now that I have added the gridView to the storyboard, I need to make sure that its cell subviews are loaded before I can call the displayDates method.

```
-(void)displayDates:(NSArray *)selectedMonthDates previousMonthVisibleDates:(NSArray *)previousMonthDates followingMonthVisibleDates:(NSArray *)followingMonthVisibleDates
    {   
        int cellNum=0;
        NSArray *displayDates[]={previousMonthDates,selectedMonthDates,followingMonthVisibleDates};
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (NSDate *d in displayDates[i])
            {            
                CalendarCellView *cell=[self.subviews objectAtIndex:cellNum];
                [cell resetState]; //initialize all properties within the CellView

                cell.date=d; // set the cell's date property to be equal to the respective date collected from the displayDate array            
                cellNum++;
            }
        }
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

So how do I make sure that the drawRect in gridView has added all of the subviews, before I come along and try to add the dates to those subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout phase is done before the rendering phase. If you are creating subviews in `drawRect` you are already doing it wrong. All "last moment" layout should be done in `-layoutSubviews:` for an `UIView` subclass which you override.

When adding to table view cell you should add your subviews to `cell.contentView` not to `cell.view` directly. See [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) paragraph **A Closer Look at Table-View Cells** for the anatomy of table view cell.

Also, you should not rely on the order of subviews in the array. Instead you should *tag* your subviews (`cellView.tag = d`) since the order of subviews is not guaranteed in view hierarchy when loaded from *nib* or *storyboard*. You can get a hold of the subview by calling `cell.contentView.viewWithTag:tag`.

And why not set the dates in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is the most common place to set values of UI elements in a table view cell.

Comment: I probably should not have used "cell" as a view name, as it is misleading I suppose since it is not in a table. I was trying to come up with a name for the "square" that holds each date on the calendar, and I came up with "cell".

Comment: Ah, I see. But I strongly recommend against doing layout in drawRect and suggest you use tags to access subviews instead of relying on a specific order in the view hierarchy. Apple has emphasized this many times over.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the view layout should have gone into drawRect so thanks for steering me away from that. Where is the best place to add the subviews from within a view? -layoutSubviews?

Comment: I actually ended up moving the bit to create the calendar "squares" up one level and changed [self addSubview:cellView] to [gridView addSubview:cellView] and that seemed to help ... for the moment

Comment: No worries about the multitude of comments :) Yes, layoutSubviews is definitely the place where you do the part of layout in your UIView subclass that changes through time. It's common pattern to create the subviews in init, but set frames in layoutSubviews.

Comment: It seems to me that layoutSubviews has more to do with redrawing views after screen changes such as rotation. Should I be managing all of my views subview via its ViewContoller instead? I'd like to load subviews from views, instead of loading them through the ViewController, but everything I read gives reference to the ViewContoller managing all of the subviews.

Comment: View Controllers deal with user interface level views. So in view controller you bring buttons, labels and text fields into the view controller's view. But some of these UI elements might consist of more than one subview. View Controllers don't deal with that complexity. All that is encapsulated in that UI element. That's when you deal with subviews within subviews. One common example would be subclassing a UITableViewCell. It's a view, but often you divide it into several subviews.